# Add executable to Windows PATH from .ebextensions and then call executable in subsequent command

Tags: windows, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, chocolatey, ebextensions

I have a Windows Elastic Beanstalk instance. I have the following `commands.config` in my project's `.ebextensions`

```
commands:
  00-install-choco:
    command: |
        powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
  01-set-choco-path:
    command: |
        SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

These two commands are working. However, I also have a `container-commands.config` file which needs to call upon `choco`, but it keeps failing due to `'choco' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

```
container_commands:
  01-install nssm:
    command: |
        choco install nssm -y
```

How do I get subsequent commands to pick up the updated `PATH`? Is there a more appropriate approach to installing binaries and setting them to Window's `PATH` during ESB instance creation?

I attempted to follow https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-nuget-and-chocolatey-package-managers-in-aws-cloudformation-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

```
files:
  c:/tools/ewmp.cmd:
    content: |
      @ECHO OFF
      FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKLMSystemCurrentControlSetControlSession ManagerEnvironment" /v PATH') DO PATH %%a%%b
      %*
commands:
  01-install-choco:
    command: powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Invoke-Expression ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
  02-install-nssm:
    command: c:/tools/ewmp choco install nssm -y
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
```

But even that gives me similar errors.

```
-----------------------Command Output-----------------------
ERROR: Invalid key name.
Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.
'choco' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a user of Elastic Beanstalk, so I can't speak to whether this will work or not, but according to the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-nuget-and-chocolatey-package-managers-in-aws-cloudformation-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) it is necessary to provide an additional command to update to PATH variable that is used:

> The Chocolatey installer and the packages it installs may modify the machine’s PATH environment variable. This adds complexity since subsequent commands after these installations are executed in the same session, which does not have the updated PATH. To overcome this, we utilize a command file to set the session’s PATH to that of the machine before it executes our command.

```
files:
  c:/tools/ewmp.cmd:
    content: |
      @ECHO OFF
      FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKLMSystemCurrentControlSetControlSession ManagerEnvironment" /v PATH') DO PATH %%a%%b
      %*
commands:
  00-install-choco:
    command: powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Invoke-Expression ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
container_commands:
  01-install nssm:
    command: |
      c:toolsewmp choco install nssm -y
```

**NOTE:** The one thing I am not clear on, based on the documentation, is the usage of `c:toolsewmp` rather than `c:/tools/ewmp` in the command section.  I don't know if this is an escaping issue in the code that is being rendered to the browser in the documentation, or whether this is intentional.  You may need to play with this to see what works.

Comment: Even with playing with different usages of ewmp, this still gives me a not recognized error. `ERROR: Invalid key name. 'choco' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: But that AWS blog post is a good find! It does explain why the PATH isn't being picked up.

Comment: Did you try the example from the article? Could it be something to do with the container command?

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely an escaping issue in the documentation, using that code as-is didn't work for me. Here is code that works:

```
files:
  c:\\tools\\ewmp.cmd:
    content: |
      @ECHO OFF
      FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH') DO PATH %%a%%b
      %*
commands:
  00_create_temp_dir:
    command: powershell.exe -Command "if (-not (Test-Path C:\\temp)) { New-Item -Path C:\\temp -ItemType Directory }"
    ignoreErrors: false
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
  01_install_chocolatey:
    command: powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Invoke-Expression ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
    ignoreErrors: false
  02_install_ffmpeg:
    command: c:\\tools\\ewmp choco install ffmpeg -y > C:\\temp\\ffmpeg_install.log 2>&1
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
    ignoreErrors: false
...
```

Although I used double-backslashes, I did test with forward slashes and it worked in most cases. I don't have a complete test matrix for that but I'll say it's flexible in that regard.